# Kodi wont let me access Ubuntu or terminal

Tags: software-uninstall, kodi

I recently installed Kodi by mistake and want my Ubuntu back. I was downloading software for Ubuntu that I thought would be useful but I didn't want a Kodi TV starter pack. What do I do?

Comment: I'm guessing; but log out and you should find yourself at the login screen. Enter your username/password but don't press <enter>. You should find a gear logo that should let you select a DEsktop - ie. Ubuntu..

Comment: @guiverc: Please post answers as _answers_. That way, if they are wrong, we can properly denote that using the community voting system, or edit the answer, or whatever. This is _especially_ important when you're unsure of the correctness of your suggestion. The comments are for critique/requesting clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

How about exiting the application? Then change your session type:

[image]

Comment: I tried but takes me right back

Comment: So you're saying it also loads back into Kodi when you reboot? If so you didn't just install kodi. Provide the exact commands you entered in your question.